# Get data from tables with one to many relation for API in Laravel

Tags: laravel, rest, api, laravel-5

I'm working on a Laravel project, and I want to create a REST Api for android application. In my system, I have two tables: categories and images. Table images has column category_id which is a foreign key that references column id on category table.

The categories table
    //users table migration

```
 class CreateCategoriessTable extends Migration
    {
        public function up()
        {
         Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->increments('id');
         $table->string('name');
         $table->timestamps();
        });
       }
...
    }
```

The images table

```
class CreateImagesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('category_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('categories')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

My Images Model:

```
class Images extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function category(){
        $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

My Category Model:

```
class Categories extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function images(){
        $this->hasMany('App\Images');
    }
}
```

So, I created a CategoryController to with the API methods, and configured the routes to access the corresponding function. The api/category/ url via GET is redirect to the index function of my controller, and the function is like that:

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::get();
    return CategoryResource::collection($categories);
}
```

With this, I can get the categories table data, but I would like merge the users and images table, and get something like this as response:

```
[
   {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'category_name',
      'images': {'image_1','image_2','image_3',...}
   }
]
```

How I can do this?Assuming that Category has many Images!!

**EDIT:::**

I created CategoryResource() class as:

```
class CategoryResource extends JsonResource

    {
          public function toArray($request)
        {
         return parent::toArray($request);
        }
    }
```

And changed the category controller to:

```
public function index()
{
    $categories= Category::with('images')->get();
    return CategoryResource::collection($categories);
}
```

suppose this returns:(actually its returning the following json in my case)

```
 {
    "data": [{
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Category1",
        "created_at": "2018-07-31 16:18:51",
        "updated_at": "2018-08-03 14:53:26",
        "images": [{
            "id": 23,
            "category_id": 6,
            "name": "category_6_31.jpg",
            "created_at": "2018-07-31 16:18:51",
            "updated_at": "2018-07-31 16:18:51"
        }, {
            "id": 27,
            "category_id": 6,
            "name": "category_6_752.jpg",
            "created_at": "2018-08-02 01:35:52",
            "updated_at": "2018-08-02 01:35:52"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Category2",
        "created_at": "2018-07-31 16:19:50",
        "updated_at": "2018-07-31 16:19:50",
        "images": [{
            "id": 24,
            "category_id":7
            "name": "product_7_1533053990.jpg",
            "created_at": "2018-07-31 16:19:50",
            "updated_at": "2018-07-31 16:19:50"
        }]
    }]
}
```

But I want to modify the JSON output as:(removing the unnecessary columns (key-value pairs)) as:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Category1",
        "images": [{
            "id": 23,
            "category_id": 6,
            "name": "category_6_31.jpg",
        }, {
            "id": 27,
            "category_id": 6,
            "name": "category_6_752.jpg",
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Category2",
        "images": [{
            "id": 24,
            "category_id":7
            "name": "product_7_1533053990.jpg",
        }]
    }]
}
```

**How to code the CategoryResource class???**
because I cannot do:::

```
return [
     'id'=>$this->id,
     'name'=>$this->name
]
```

this will throw an error....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::with('images')->get();
        return response()->json($categories,200);
    }
```

Comment: Yes this will do the trick but Please read the edited part of the question I have added some more...

Comment: Also I did not get the last line of your answer. I am using CategoryResource class as well, not directly returning the JSON data from the controller

Comment: have a look at this https://hackernoon.com/reusable-api-resource-with-nested-relationship-laravel-5-5-c654c7243869